# how to generate a rtf file with qt?

Tags: html, qt, rtf

Software: Visual Studio 2008 +QT

Targets:
              1. Generate an **editable** report including texts and tables

Based conditions:
              1.An report generated from html
              2.Got a report in Pdf

```
          ![enter image description here][1]
```

Questions:
               Since the Pdf format cannot be editted,I'm considering to RTF,which is editable.But I don't know how to accomplish it.

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

KWord is Qt-based, LGPL-licensed and it exports RTF. Maybe you can reuse KWord's RTF export filter or study it to make your own RTF generator.

Get the latest source code from http://download.kde.org/stable/koffice-latest/

The interesting code can be found from the tarball under `koffice-<version>/filters/kword/rtf/export/`